# escaping +- and -- in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to replace all occurrences of +- with - from a string called myStr in java. 
I also want to replace all occurrences of -- with + from myStr. 
The following two lines of code are not accomplishing this in java:

```
myStr.replaceAll("\\+-", "-");  
myStr.replaceAll("\\--", "+");
```

Can anyone show me how to alter these two lines of code to accomplish the desired replacements?

I usually try to avoid regular expressions, but am not sure how to do this operation without them.

Comment: Use the backslash before the character you want to escape: `\+\-` and `\-\-`.

Comment: @Jerry Thanks.  I tried newSubStr.replaceAll("\+\-", "-");  but eclipse is giving me the following error message now: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

Comment: You'll have a problem when you'll have `---` since it will print `-+` although, I guess, you want it to be `-`.

Comment: What do you expect to happen with `+--`?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker Thanks.  But the logic of my program is extremely unlikely to produce +--.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're throwing out the return value of the function. You probably want to use:

```
myStr = myStr.replaceAll("\\+-", "-").replaceAll("--", "+");
```

---

<sub>update with additional info from comment:</sub>

Be sure to keep the return value of `replaceAll`.

```
myStr = myStr.replaceAll("\\+-", "-");
```

and later

```
myStr = myStr.replaceAll("--", "+");
```

Comment: No need to escape the dash.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done anything with regexes in Java

Comment: @zzzzBov Thanks.  But these two lines are in different sections of my code, so bundling them is not an option.  I just put them together above for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String escapePlusMinus(String myStr) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[+-]-");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myStr);
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (matcher.group(0).equals("+-")) {
            matcher.appendReplacement(result, "-");
        }
        else {
            matcher.appendReplacement(result, "+");
        }
    }
    matcher.appendTail(result);

    return result.toString();
}
```

`escapePlusMinus("+-, --, +-, ---+---")` ⇒ `"-, +, -, +--+"`

The last token is matched as:

1. `"--"` ⇒ `"+"`
2. `"-"` skipped, since there are not another `"-"` following it.
3. `"+-"` ⇒ `"-"`
4. `"--"` ⇒ `"+"`